# Динамическое изменение путей ресурсов в Gulp в зависимости от вложенности файлов

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, gulp

Я работаю над проектом, в котором использую Gulp для автоматизации моих задач сборки. У меня есть проблема, с которой я столкнулся и которую не могу решить самостоятельно.

Моя структура проекта включает HTML-файлы, которые находятся на разных уровнях вложенности. В этих HTML-файлах я подключаю различные ресурсы (такие как CSS, JS, изображения, href и т.д.) с помощью атрибута src. Проблема в том, что пути к этим ресурсам должны изменяться в зависимости от уровня вложенности HTML-файла.

Например, если у меня есть HTML-файл в корневой директории, путь к ресурсу может выглядеть так: src="img/my-image.jpg". Но если HTML-файл находится в поддиректории, путь должен быть изменен на src="../img/my-image.jpg".

Я ищу способ автоматически изменять эти пути во время сборки Gulp. Я пробовал использовать gulp-replace с функцией обратного вызова, которая вычисляет уровень вложенности файла и изменяет путь соответствующим образом, но это вызвало ошибку “Callback called multiple times”.

Есть ли у кого-нибудь идеи или предложения, как я могу решить эту проблему? Любые советы или направления будут очень ценными.
[image: таск html]
Спасибо заранее!

До инфа: app это глобальный объект в gulp
[image: 23]

path - это объект с путями к раным файлам для разных тасков
plugins -это объект с часто используемыми плагинами что их постоянно не импортировать

Я пробовал использовать gulp-replace с функцией обратного вызова, которая вычисляет уровень вложенности файла и изменяет путь соответствующим образом, но это вызвало ошибку “Callback called multiple times”.
[image: a]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)